# How to do select count(*) group by and select * at same time?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, I have table:

```
ID   |   Value
1         hi
1         yo
2         foo
2         bar
2         hehe
3         ha
6         gaga
```

I want my query to get ID, Value; meanwhile the returned set should be in the order of frequency count of each ID.

I tried the query below but don't know how to get the ID and Value column at the same time:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE group by ID order by COUNT(*) desc;
```

The count number doesn't matter to me, I just need the data to be in such order.

Desire Result:

```
ID   |   Value

2         foo
2         bar
2         hehe
1         hi
1         yo
3         ha
6         gaga

As you can see because ID:2 appears most times(3 times), it's first on the list, 
then ID:1(2 times) etc.
```

Comment: can you put the desired result?

Comment: post your input set and desired output set

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  Or MySQL?  You've tagged this for two different databases but the different databases will often support slightly different syntax.

Comment: @JustinCave Should be oracle, I don't know the difference in syntax..

Comment: Where is your table structure and what is the unique key?? put more details about that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t.id, t.value
from TABLE t
inner join 
(
  SELECT id, count(*) as cnt 
  FROM TABLE 
  group by ID
)
x on x.id = t.id
order by x.cnt desc
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try this -

```
    select id, value, count(*) over (partition by id)  freq_count
from
(
select 2  as ID,  'foo' as value
from dual
union all
select 2,         'bar'
from dual
union all
select 2,         'hehe'
from dual
union all
select 1 ,        'hi'
from dual
union all
select 1  ,       'yo'
from dual
union all
select 3   ,      'ha'
from dual
union all
select 6    ,     'gaga'
from dual
)
order by 3 desc;
```

Comment: @astander, what are you talking about? This will work in Oracle. In fact it has advantages over the other alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like

```
SELECT  t.ID,
        t.Value,
        c.Cnt
FROM    TABLE t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID,
                    COUNT(*) Cnt
            FROM    TABLE
            GROUP BY ID
        ) c ON  t.ID = c.ID
ORDER BY c.Cnt DESC
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fffe/2)

Answer (score 1):

I see the question is already answered, but since the most obvious and most simple solution is missing, I'm posting it anyway. It doesn't use self joins nor subqueries:

```
SQL> create table t (id,value)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'hi' from dual union all
  4  select 1, 'yo' from dual union all
  5  select 2, 'foo' from dual union all
  6  select 2, 'bar' from dual union all
  7  select 2, 'hehe' from dual union all
  8  select 3, 'ha' from dual union all
  9  select 6, 'gaga' from dual
 10  /

Table created.

SQL> select id
  2       , value
  3    from t
  4   order by count(*) over (partition by id) desc
  5  /

        ID VALU
---------- ----
         2 bar
         2 hehe
         2 foo
         1 yo
         1 hi
         6 gaga
         3 ha

7 rows selected.
```